# How to add Google material icon "my location" on google map V2 in android?

Tags: android, android-studio, material-design, google-maps-android-api-2

I am trying to show maps in android using API v2.

I want Google material icon "my location" on map. But, whenever I try to add in layout, it does not reflect in output.

I am able to get maps without icon. I need icon to integrate with map.

When I write ImageButton code outside the fragment tag, icon displays in preview pane, but not inside it.

where should I put the ImageButton code?

code for Mylayout.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </fragment>

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/ic_gps"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_my_location_black_18dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Link:- https://design.google.com/icons/#ic_my_location

Comment: Do you mean the default Find My Location button?

Answer (score 0):

Get your map object (mMap) and call `setMyLocationEnabled(boolean)` on it.

`mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);`

This will add the default image button that initiates a 'find my location' action.